# PowerBI CLI node: No such file or directory

Tags: php, node.js, linux, powerbi, macos-sierra

I am trying to build `PHP` wrapper for `PowerBI`. I installed `PowerBI Cli` (https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Cli) on my local and when I run any PowerBI Cli command on my terminal, it is working well. It is working well even when I run the commands using the `_www` user (`sudo -u _www powerbi config`)

However, when I run them through `PHP` using either `shell_exec` or `Symphony's Process Component` (https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html), I am getting the following exception:

```
env: node: No such file or directory.
```

I am facing this issue on `Mac Sierra`. The commands are working well on `Linux` using the PHP `exec()`

Comment: sounds like a ´$PATH´ problem. Is it possible, that your PHP environments are executed as another user, than you normally use? e.g. cause you are ´sudo´ -ing?

Comment: The PHP environment is executed as `_www` user. What is strange is that when I run the command as a _www user from the terminal, it is working well. However, this is not a case if I run it through PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Try [linking](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uln.htm),

```
"ln -s /path/where/command/is stored/ /to/path/where u want to exec/"
```

Sometimes the program are stored in `usr/local/bin/program` meanwhile as per default you are executing in `usr/bin/program`

And then in shell use the new path you have set.

Example for linking suppose if you have path for command,

`/usr/bin/powerbi` then with above command you can link new path `usr/powerbi` after that you can use new path in exec or shell command.

Comment: If you provide your original path so i can check this on my side.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the full path rather than the command. Without knowing your exact path I can't tell you exactly what to do but it would be something like this:

```
$output = shell_exec("sudo -u _www /path/path/powerbi config");
var_dump($output);
```

Edit:

Or, change directories first. So using my example above, it would be:

```
$output = shell_exec("cd /path/path/powerbi; sudo -u _www powerbi config");
```

Comment: Yeah, that is how I am using it. No luck with that.

Comment: Have you tried changing directories to it first, then running it? I edited my answer with another attempt for you to try.

Comment: Yes, here is how I am executing it - `sudo -u _www /usr/local/bin/powerbi config`.

Comment: If that's not working, try cd first and issue two commands. I edited my answer to include it.

Comment: Nope. That doesn't work either. Setting up Virtual Machine - something I should have done it before :)